# Execute sript shell script with remote command from php

Tags: php, shell, ssh, remote-access

I try execute this script from my php but I retrieve error not permission to execute from hostkey invalid.

```
ssh myuser@hostname "mkdir /home/userhome/teste555"
```

My php

```
$message=shell_exec("/var/www/html/x.sh 2>&1");
  print_r($message);
```

return result:

> Could not create directory '/var/www/.ssh'. Host key verification failed.

I have access to server, but my user executing command is `www-data`

Answer (score 0):

It means that host key of the remote server was changed.

Edit `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file to remove the host name or IP address of the remote server.

Or use the command to do this directly:

`ssh-keygen -R hostname`